# Number of vertices in the Klein bottle triangulation given in "Topology and geometry for physicists" by Nash and Sen

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation, klein-bottle

I stumbled upon the following triangulation of the Klein Bottle in page 76 of the book *Topology and geometry for physicists* by Charles Nash and Siddhartha Sen.

[image]

Below the figure, it says "the triangulation $K$ consists of **eight** $0$-simplexes[...]".

I think this is not an eight-vertex triangulation, but rather a **nine**-vertex triangulation of the Klein bottle. I also know, thanks to the great comments under [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453419/minimal-triangulation-of-klein-bottle#_=_) question, that an $8$-vertex triangulation of the Klein bottle is a minimal one, hence the one portrayed in the book isn't minimal.

Am I correct?

Comment: Note that the Euler characteristic of the Klein bottle is zero, so the numbers given for this illustration can't be right, since $8-27+18 \neq 0$. Indeed the 8 should be a 9.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri That's a good point. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a nine-vertex triangulation: the vertices are in fact numbered for you: 0, 1, 2, ..., 8. You've pointed out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453419/minimal-triangulation-of-klein-bottle#_=_), so I will add a link to the [paper by Davide Cervone](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/papers/1993-03.KB/vmkb.pdf) cited at that question, which gives a proof that there have to be at least 8 vertices, plus a classification of all 8-vertex triangulations.